# How to run Appium tests with WebdriverIO (Android) in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: java, azure-devops, sdk, azure-pipelines, appium

I have a test that I want to run in Azure DevOps Pipeline. I'm using Appium and WebdriverIO.

I have done it locally and it worked fine. I have installed an Android emulator from Android Studio and set the SDK and JDK paths.

The problem now is that I need to create a pipeline to run the test. I have no idea how should I do it.

How should I set the SDK and JDK in Azure DevOps. For your information, I don't use YAML. I use classic editor.

I know how to create a pipeline to run Cypress tests. But Appium, Nope

Answer (score 0):

Hello everything is fine? well I believe that on your machine locally you installed the appium-doctor, node, and the appium, the pipeline is no different. To install and validate all the same steps on the machine, you must install everything via script in a macOS virtual machine, as shown in the example below:

```
pool:
  vmImage: macOS-10.15
          - script: npm install -g appium@1.21.0 # --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
        displayName: "Install appium 1.21.0"

      - task: NodeTool@0
        condition: always()
        inputs:
          versionSpec: "16.x"
        displayName: Install Node Js

      - task: Bash@3
        displayName: "Run Appium in background port 4723"
        continueOnError: false
        enabled: true
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            #!/bin/bash
            nohup appium -a 127.0.0.1 -p 4723 --relaxed-security > $(agent.buildDirectory)/s/folderReports/appium_log_4723.txt &

      - script: npm install -g appium-doctor
        continueOnError: true
        enabled: true
        displayName: "Install appium doctor"
      - script: appium-doctor
        continueOnError: true
        enabled: true
        displayName: "Check appium doctor"
```

The Android Emulator "Task Script"you can instantiate it as follows:

```
          - task: Bash@3
        displayName: Run Emulator
        enabled: true
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Neh0h.png)

MORE INFORMATION: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/android?view=azure-devops

I'm sorry if I didn't understand, it's my first answer here on this channel

Comment: Did anyone get this to work? I am  facing the same challenge here and would like to know how to do this. I tutorial or something would be nice.